# Asynchronous TCP Socket Issue

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, parallel-processing

Well, I need to connect to a TCP socket, however, it only accepts one connection at a time and has a 60 second timeout.

The problem is that in the process of sending information and receiving a response, the application is not performative.

I would like to know, if in this case, it is possible to do something asynchronous/parallel.

Below is my socket client class.

```
public class TcpSocketClient
{
    public TcpClient TCPConnection { get; private set; }

    private int BUFFER_SIZE = 259;

    public TcpSocketClient Connect(IPEndPoint endpoint)
    {
        try
        {
            this.TCPConnection = new TcpClient(endpoint);
            return this;
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception($"{ex.Message} - {ex.StackTrace}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Err: {ex.Message} - {ex.StackTrace}");
        }
    }

    public T SendRequest<T>(IFrame request) where T : IFrame, new()
    {
        var data = request.ToByteArray();

        var stream = this.TCPConnection.GetStream();
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        data = new byte[this.BUFFER_SIZE];
        var quantityBytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

        var frameResponse = data.Take(quantityBytes).ToArray();

        var response = new T
        {
            FrameHeader = frameResponse[0],
            Lenght = frameResponse[1],
            FunctionCode = frameResponse[2],
            Data = (frameResponse[1] == 0) ? null : data.ToDataField(quantityBytes),
            Checksum = frameResponse[frameResponse.Length - 1]
        };

        (response.Checksum != response.VerifyChecksum()) { throw new Exception("Err in Checksum!"); }

        return response;
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        this.TCPConnection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is absolutely possible to handle sockets using async, but... it can be pretty complex. The `Socket` type actually has 2 complete async APIs (being/end, and socketasynceventargs), and `NetworkStream` has the async stream API. But... you can't just throw these in blindly. Async sockets are *really* quite hard to do short examples of. Note: parallel *is* an option, but doesn't scale very well unless you only have a handful of connections to worry about. If you have hundreds, thousands, etc : don't go "parallel" - go async

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your code to be async:

```
public async Task<T> SendRequest<T>(IFrame request) where T : IFrame, new()
{
    var data = request.ToByteArray();

    var stream = this.TCPConnection.GetStream();
    await stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);

    data = new byte[this.BUFFER_SIZE];
    var quantityBytes = await stream.ReadAsync(data, 0, data.Length);

    var frameResponse = data.Take(quantityBytes).ToArray();

    var response = new T
    {
        FrameHeader = frameResponse[0],
        Lenght = frameResponse[1],
        FunctionCode = frameResponse[2],
        Data = (frameResponse[1] == 0) ? null : data.ToDataField(quantityBytes),
        Checksum = frameResponse[frameResponse.Length - 1]
    };

    if(response.Checksum != response.VerifyChecksum())
        throw new Exception("Err in Checksum!");

    return response;
}
```

To call it use:

```
MyFrameResponseType response = await SendRequest(yourRequest);
```

Also, as a note, that code assumes you will receive a response with only one read, that will fail on a future, if the network is slow or the sent response is big enough it will be received in multiple read operations, you should have some mechanism to detect a frame start/end and read until you have received a full frame.